# How do i install PyQt5 with python 3.7.0a2 on windows 10

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-sip

I am new to all of this and I am trying to install PyQt5, I entered "pip install pyqt5" and this is what happened - ( its cached because of previous download attempt)

C:\Users\Liam>pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.9.1-5.9.2-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from pyqt5)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from pyqt5) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from pyqt5)

Can anyone give me some pointers I am completely lost.

Thank you for any help that you can give me

Liam

Comment: Please notice the `a` as in "alpha" in the version number. Use a final version of Python to solve the installation problem.

Comment: Ok i will give it a go, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You were right, it didnt occur to me at all i stupidly just went for the highest number, i spent ages trying to solve that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python 3.4 Pyqt 5 works with it

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid version number.  You have to use a final version of python (as stated in Klaus D.'s comment).